# PBC element_to_bytes error "prints garbage" Unable to convert element to string

Tags: c, malloc

I am getting garbage values when I convert an element_t to string. What could be the reason?

```
element_printf("element_a: %B",a);

//int len = element_length_in_bytes(a);
unsigned char* strA= (unsigned char*)malloc(element_length_in_bytes(a)*sizeof(char));
element_to_bytes(strA,a);
printf("\n\n\n a: %s\n\n\n",strA);
```

The output is:

```
element_a: 676879270129030191324293305775237511254264666883


 a: v�P��?�P�+��a�����[
```

I want the normal a to print as the element_a. What am I missing?

Thanks,
Yogesh

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting garbage and you are not converting your element to a string. You are passing an array of bytes to printf and tell this function to interpret them as characters. No surprise this does not work. Try element_snprint()

```
element_printf("element_a: %B",a);

size_t s = (size_t) element_length_in_bytes(a);
char* strA= (char*)malloc(s*sizeof(char));
element_snprint(strA, s, a)
printf("\n\n\n a: %s\n\n\n",strA);
```

Comment: I am getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. Could you kindly check again?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up two functions. See the edited answer.

Comment: I am only getting a partial output as shown element_a: 123832556562094194634656047429957700835080349207
a: 1238325565620941946

Comment: I don't have PBC installed here, so probably it should be you to play around these errors. It's clear that in my solution s is not big enough so a buffer of size s cannot hold the whole element. ust increase the buffer size. Find out what causes the difference between element_length_in_bytes and the length of the string representation.